# PyMySql installs in Camel Case, but imports in lower case?

Tags: python, pymysql

Would one of you Pythonistas please explain why [PyMySql](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL) installs in Camel Case, but imports in lower case?

```
>>>pip freeze   
PyMySQL==0.6.2 

>>> import PyMySql
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named PyMySql
>>> import pymysql
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/tree/master/pymysql the package is pymysql (Folder with **init**.py in it) and not PyMySql. So 'import pymysql' is the right way to do it. How you install is part of setup and they are not related.

Answer (score 1):

The name in PyPI and listed in `pip freeze` is defined in the package's setup.py.  The name you `import` is the directory name the package is installed in to site packages in.  These have no inherent relationship at all, it is only convenience and convention that keeps them the same or similar in most packages.